# How to make ajax call and get results back while typing in input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I want to implement some functionality which is when I enter some text in

```
<input path="tags" id="input-search"/>
```

there should appear a list of suggested **tags** just like 
[image: Tages]

after making ajax call. I have database query

```
public interface TagRepository extends JpaRepository<Tag, Integer> {    
    @Query("SELECT t FROM Tag t WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', :name, '%')")
    List<Tag> findTagByName(@Param("name") String name);    
}
```

and the controller code is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getTags", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public  @ResponseBody List<Tag> getTags(@RequestBody Tag tag, HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println("Found " + String.valueOf(tagService.findTagByName(tag.getName()).size()));
        return tagService.findTagByName(tag.getName());

    }
```

javascript for ajax is

```
 $(document).ready(function() {   
        $("#tag-search").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                 url: "/app/getTags/", 
                 type: "POST", 
                 data: JSON.stringify({tag : request.term}),
                 dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data, function(v,i){
                        console.log();
                        return {
                            label: v.empName,
                            value: v.empName
                         };
                    }));
                }
               });              
            }   
        });
    });

<div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1">                                                   
    <label class="floating-label" for="login-username">Tags</label>
    <form:input path="tags" cssClass="form-control" id="tag-search"/>
</div>
```

when I run the app I see this javaScript error in Developers Tools
[image: Snapshot]

### Important

I'm using [Daemonite/material](https://github.com/Daemonite/material) for my front-end & [jQuery-Autocomplete](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete), finally a good thing is that the latest version of App is [on GitHub](https://github.com/springcrazy/ask-spring)
can any one tell me how can I get rid of *that* error any response is welcome.

Comment: Thanks a lot for adding bounty would any one give me answer of this now?

Comment: Your Ajax response will be java List can you try returning it as string by parsing it as Json from controller method itself. Can you pls try this and share the result.

Comment: how can I parse to json please?

Comment: Below is using Jackson. call this function with your list  as toJson(tagService.findTagByName(tag.getName()))                        public static String toJSON(Object object) {
  if ( object == null ) {
   return "{}";
  }
  try {
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   return mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } 
  return "{}";
 } . You need jackson-core-2.2.3.jar, jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar and jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar

Comment: `console.log(data)` and check whether you are getting proper response. Also try to `parseJson` before anyother process.. like in `success` write `var parsedData=$.parseJSON(data);` and then with normal things..

Comment: Could you please note filepaths for your Git Hub project for each of your code snippets there is alot of code in that project. Your problem is in your Java code have you checked what is coming back from your call? To do this open the developer console then make the request though the browser click the network tab at the top and then click on the request to `/app/getTags/` and put a copy of the response tab's information to SO as a code block

Comment: @MartinBarker I don't get any thing in response I think even the method is not called.

Answer (score 4):

for the problem above i mostly use **[select2 jquery plugin](http://select2.github.io/select2)**. it's has a lot of build in feature, so no need of reinventing the wheel. check this link out for a demo - http://select2.github.io/select2/#infinite

screen shot:

[image]

code sample:

```
$("#e7").select2({
    placeholder: "Search for a repository",
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
        url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
        dataType: 'json',
        quietMillis: 250,
        data: function (term, page) { // page is the one-based page number tracked by Select2
            return {
                q: term, //search term
                page: page // page number
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
            var more = (page * 30) < data.total_count; // whether or not there are more results available

            // notice we return the value of more so Select2 knows if more results can be loaded
            return { results: data.items, more: more };
        }
    },
    formatResult: repoFormatResult, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
    formatSelection: repoFormatSelection, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
    dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop", // apply css that makes the dropdown taller
    escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; } // we do not want to escape markup since we are displaying html in results
});
```

now layout is not exactly same as screenshot you provided, but check if this layout work for you.

Update:

```
function repoFormatResult(repo) {
  var markup = '<div class="row-fluid">' +
     '<div class="span2"><img src="' + repo.owner.avatar_url + '" /></div>' +
     '<div class="span10">' +
        '<div class="row-fluid">' +
           '<div class="span6">' + repo.full_name + '</div>' +
           '<div class="span3"><i class="fa fa-code-fork"></i> ' + repo.forks_count + '</div>' +
           '<div class="span3"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> ' + repo.stargazers_count + '</div>' +
        '</div>';

  if (repo.description) {
     markup += '<div>' + repo.description + '</div>';
  }

  markup += '</div></div>';

  return markup;
}

function repoFormatSelection(repo) {
    return repo.full_name;
}
```

**Another approach:**

Hi if above solution not fit for your problem then you  can use this one instead. it's called [typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) a JavaScript library provide by twitter. you can find examples [here](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/).

Comment: Can you provide some code for `formatResult: repoFormatResult, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
    formatSelection: repoFormatSelection, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page` lines

Comment: Hi traveling in this moment. Will try to update you in 1 or 2 days.

Comment: OK I'll be waiting for your kind response!

Comment: Hi, hope u  able to figure out the solution for your problem. i posted another alternative called typeahead.js, see if that helped too. if this help you please consider for up-vote.

Answer (score 2):

Check jquery vendor library is loaded properly or not.

To cross check:

```
<script>
if (window.jQuery) {  
    alert('jQuery is loaded');
} else {
    alert('jQuery is not loaded');
}
</script>
```

Comment: It says __jQuery is not loaded__

Comment: Try to add <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" />"></script> before our checking code.

Comment: Ok that resolves javascript problem but still unable to make an ajax call and get results back.

Comment: Also, check whether autocomplete library loaded properly

Comment: You mean to say should I check like if (window.jquery.autocomplete)  because file name is _jquery.autocomplete.min.js_

Comment: you check for `jQuery.fn.autocomplete` E.G `if(typeof jQuery.fn.autocomplete == undefined) throw "jquery.autocomplete.min.js is not loaded";`

Comment: @MartinBarker: how is your suggestion relevant to the exception?

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that you are getting HTML instead of JSON in response.

"*Unexpected <*" is referring to the first character of your request's response.
in chrome console you can go to network tab and click on your request and in the right side see what exactly your server is returning back to client.

Answer (score 0):

You missed jquery.js. Add it and you'll get it working.

Comment: I have an structured Spring MVC project which uses Apache Tiles I have configured & included jQuery in my project

Comment: Check the view source of your page and click on the jquery.js link. If it displays jquery.js content that has been added. If 404, there is an issue with jquery.js linking.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding the codes here so that it would be better readable;

Write a new method to parse json on Java side before returning to jquery. Current code returns Java list as output for Ajax and this would possibly throw Uncaught syntax error : Unexpected token.

```
     public static String toJSON(Object object) 
      { 
          if ( object == null ){
          return "{}"; 
          } 
          try { 
             ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
             return mapper.writeValueAsString(object); 
             } 
          catch (Exception e) { 
           e.printStackTrace(); 
          } 
        return "{}"; 
        }
```

for the above piece of code you need to include 3 jars jackson-core-2.2.3.jar, jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar and jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar.

Change you controller as following;

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getTags", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public  @ResponseBody String getTags(@RequestBody Tag tag, HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println("Found " + String.valueOf(tagService.findTagByName(tag.getName()).size()));
        return toJSON(tagService.findTagByName(tag.getName()));

    }
$(document).ready(function() { 
        var autoCompleteResult = '';  
        $("#tag-search").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                 url: "/app/getTags/", 
                 type: "POST", 
                 data: JSON.stringify({tag : request.term}),
                 dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    autoCompleteResult = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    response($.map(autoCompleteResult, function(v,i){
                        console.log();
                        return {
                            label: v.empName,
                            value: v.empName
                         };
                    }));
                }
               });              
            }   
        });
    });
```

Please share your results after trying this.

Comment: Still facing the same problem can you please get a clone of my project and make some changes there from link given above.

Comment: It will be a great help if you spend some time on that particular task/issue. Please

Comment: edited my answer to parse string from java to json using jquery please try this.

Comment: Can you print what you are getting as data after Ajax call, output after parsing it as json and share here? Without that I cant offer much of help.

Comment: Thanks a lot Man! I wasted your time again and again but got __ZERO__ result, I'm leaving the discussion and leaving the problem unsolved, because I don't have any Idea what to do I'm in pressure, if you still have interest to solve this problem then go ahead and fork the app from github and let me now what you came up with if no then Thanks again.

Comment: @MartinBarker what is your solution? you have any? if its code review you need to go to different forum.

Comment: `toJSON(Object object) ` i said you should have used obj or something E.G `toJSON(Object obj) `

Comment: @MartinBarker what is the point of object name in solution? clearly his problem is to get that working not to comply with standards. I think you didnt get the point that its not about code review and standards its about solution.

Comment: @MartinBarkerI cant stop laughing at you. You need to learn Java basics,before you comment on something. Here is the first point for you to learn keywords in Java from Oracle website: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html If you find Object as keyword please feel free to report here back, else you come and accept you have NO knowledge in basic Java :P

Comment: @MartinBarker You seem to have deleted your comments about Horrific programming definition and sole purpose of stack overflow, would you mind accepting you are just an empty vessel who made a loud noise? Its so bad that you are very arrogant to accept that you made a mistake and down voted someone's post without knowing very basic Java keywords. Grow up and accept. everyone makes mistakes

Comment: @NightsWatch you know what i don't care i was trying to help prevent future problems since some one could move to C,C++ or C# from java and not even think about `object` as Java is supposed to be C Syntax funny thing is i have built software in use around the world in Java and C# so i must not have a clue how to use java

Comment: @MartinBarker I appreciate your point and intention that you wanted to prevent future problems, but now even after understanding that object is not keyword(reason behind you downvoting) you are still not accepting the misunderstanding and remove your downvote. Whole point I am trying to make is the solution which I suggested might not have worked in this case but it will work for someone else. But just because of your downvote[reason being different] someone might not even try this.

Comment: @NightsWatch ok don't you know Stack overflow does not allow removing of down votes after a day unless the answer is edited

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
https://github.com/tanwaniniranjan/autosuggest
It's a plugin made for the same purpose. very less documentation, but i hope to put up the documentation soon.

Yu can read the comments in the js file to get an idea on the usage

Edit:
I now read your question more carefully,
what is happening is:
the response that you are getting from the server side is giving an error.
the error will usually start like sorry bro, 404

since you are trying to map the data, jQuery just cant parse it, and it gives you the error.
check your server side first. use the postman plugin to make requests, verify your response and then implement jQuery: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-launcher/igofndmniooofoabmmpfonmdnhgchoka?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

As i see there could be a issue of `500 internal server error` because you have a `dataType: "json",` in your ajax while at your controller you aren't returning any `json`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getTags", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public  @ResponseBody List<Tag> getTags(@RequestBody Tag tag, HttpServletResponse response) {
    System.out.println("Found " + String.valueOf(tagService.findTagByName(tag.getName()).size()));
    return tagService.findTagByName(tag.getName());

}
```

Here at your conroller this: `produces = "application/json"` says it will return json as output and with this: `return tagService.findTagByName(tag.getName());` you can producing any `json`.

Comment: Thanks for your precious time I have tried this as well  [At This Line](https://github.com/springcrazy/ask-spring/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rhcloud/crazy/controller/QuestionController.java#L70), but still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just add below tag to your ajax call

```
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

> This is the type for requested data,in your case it simply text format that you type in text box
>
> And remove below line from your ajax call if your response data is not json type

`dataType: 'json',`
This may remove Json Parsing Error in your code

Answer (score 0):

Change your JavaScript as the below

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $("#tag-search").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
             contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
             url: "/app/getTags/", 
             type: "POST", 
             data: JSON.stringify({'tag' : "'"+request.term+"'"}),
             dataType: "json",
             success: function(data) {
                response($.map(data, function(v,i){
                    console.log();
                    return {
                        label: v.empName,
                        value: v.empName
                     };
                }));
            }
           });              
        }   
    });
});
```