# Can not make ajax call to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

I've tried to use ajax in Spring MVC App but it seems not working I searched for that and found many resources but as I'm not a pro I could not understand any of those, finally I found [this tutorial](https://javatutorials13.wordpress.com/2014/04/03/jquerys-autocomplete-functionality-in-a-spring-mvc-application/) as a grace and tried in Controller as

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getBars", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public  @ResponseBody List<Bar> getBars(@RequestParam String bar, HttpServletResponse response) {
        return barService.findBarByName(bar);

    }
```

and javascript is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("#bar-search").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/app/getBars",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { term: request.term },

                    dataType: "json",

                    success: function(data) {
                        response($.map(data, function(v,i){
                            return {
                                        label: v.empName,
                                        value: v.empName
                                       };
                        }));
                    }
               });              
            }   
        });
    });
});
```

and finally my view.jsp is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" name="viewport">
    <title>Ask Question</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"/></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"> </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/app/resources/js/autoComplete.js"></script>
    <script>
        if (window.jQuery) {  
            alert('jQuery is loaded');
        } else {
            alert('jQuery is not loaded');
        }                                   
    </script>
    <!-- css -->
    <link href="/app/resources/css/base.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- favicon -->
    <!-- ... -->

    <!-- ie -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
<div class="form-group form-group-label">
     <div class="row">                                          
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1">                                                   
            <label class="floating-label" for="login-username">Bars</label>
                <input id="bar-search" name="bars" class="form-control" type="text" value=""/>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
<script src="/crazy/resources/js/base.min.js;jsessionid=4891173C4BB89D06603ACA4FF7D64D20" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/crazy/resources/js/webfont.js;jsessionid=4891173C4BB89D06603ACA4FF7D64D20" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/crazy/resources/js/jquery.autocomplete.min.js;jsessionid=4891173C4BB89D06603ACA4FF7D64D20" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

every thing is ok when app starts but when I write some text down in input I get error

[image]
can any one solve this error for me or tell me where am I wrong.
sorry if my English is incorrect.

Comment: What does the server respond to the POST request with?  My guess is it's not responding with valid JSON...

Comment: How can I check server reponse!

Comment: @KenFranqueiro please see my update

Comment: Yes, your server is most definitely not responding with valid JSON.  To see the response, open your browser's developer tools, go to the network tab, and find the request to `/app/getBars` in it.  Alternatively, for testing purposes, temporarily change `dataType` to `text` and log the value you get in your `success` callback.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {});` and `$(function() {});` are the same thing, why do you have one inside the other..

Comment: @Adelphia As I said earlier I'm beginner so please suggest me solution.

Comment: Use a restclient like postman to check your server side. Make the post call and verify the server works fine. Then concentrate on the client javascript part.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... the first thing is that your service is configured wrongly.

Your service wants a @RequestParam, but in your ajax you are sending a json object which means you should be accepting a @RequestBody.

Also, if you are looking for a @RequestParam, you need to pass the value as part of the url like...

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/app/getBars?bar=" + request.term,
    type: "GET"          
    ( ... )
});   

@RequestMapping(value = "/getBars", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public  @ResponseBody List<Bar> getBars(@RequestParam(value = "bar", defaultValue = "abc", required = false) String bar, HttpServletResponse response) {
    return barService.findBarByName(bar);

}
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/app/getBars/" + request.term,
    type: "GET"          
    ( ... )
}); 

@RequestMapping(value = "/getBars/{bar}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public  @ResponseBody List<Bar> getBars(@PathVariable String bar, HttpServletResponse response) {
    return barService.findBarByName(bar);

}
```

For a post.

First create a bean.

```
public class MyRequestBean implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String bar;

    public void setBar(String bar){
         this.bar = bar;
    }

    public void getBar(){
        return this.bar;
    }

}
```

and then write your service like this...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getBars", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public  @ResponseBody List<Bar> getBars(@RequestBody MyRequestBean bean, HttpServletResponse response) {
    return barService.findBarByName(bean.getBar());

}

$.ajax({ 
    url: "/app/getBars/,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({bar : request.term})
    ( ... )
});
```

NOTE: never have the verbs defining your service.

For example, **/getBars** can be changed to just **/bars** and let the **HTTP protocol (GET, POST, PUT or DELETE etc..)** descide which operation you are trying to perform.

Comment: same problem Unexpected token < !!

Comment: If it is a get request, type the url in the browser and see what the response is and also do you have spring security?

Comment: I don't have spring security

Comment: Please have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32857823/how-to-make-ajax-call-and-get-results-back-while-typing-in-input-text), it has also same issue as this one have.